# The numba fibonacci function is slower and does not return the same result

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, numba

This code return slow and with different output:

---

```
from numba import jit
from timeit import default_timer as timer
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = a+b, a
    return a
fibonacci_jit = jit(fibonacci)
```

## let start the test

```
start = timer()
print fibonacci(100)
duration = timer() - start
```

## let start the test

```
startnext = timer()
print fibonacci_jit(100)
durationnext = timer() - startnext


print(duration, durationnext)
```

The result:

```
C:\Python27>python numba_test_003.py
927372692193078999176
1445263496
(0.00038264393810854576, 0.17378674127528523)
```

#next

```
C:\Python27>python numba_test_003.py
927372692193078999176
1445263496
(0.0004830358514597401, 0.19266426987655644)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only running your Numba jitted function once, you're seeing the sum of the jit compilation time and the run time. The next time you run the numba function, you'll only see the runtime and it will be faster since numba caches the compiled code for each unique set of input parameter types:

```
startnext = timer()
print fibonacci_jit(100)
durationnext = timer() - startnext
print(duration, durationnext)

#5035488507601418376
#(0.0003879070281982422, 0.14705300331115723)

startnext = timer()
print fibonacci_jit(100)
durationnext = timer() - startnext

print(duration, durationnext)

#5035488507601418376
#(0.0003879070281982422, 0.0002810955047607422)
```

The difference in answers is due to the fact that the Python native object `int` is infinite precision, whereas numba is using a C-like native `int` that has limited capacity and can be overflowed. If you run the function with smaller inputs, you should see that it agrees up until you overflow the numba int.

Comment: Ah, I should've refreshed the page. Sorry for posting an answer containing (almost) the same explanations.

Comment: Showing `inspect_types` is useful, so +1 for that.

Comment: no the deafult function  fibonacci(100) come with this : result 927372692193078999176 and time 0.00038264393810854576 and the jit result is 1445263496 and time is 0.17378674127528523.

Comment: @CătălinGeorgeFeștilă - correct, but my answer (and @MSeifert's) address why this is the case (1) cost of compilation time the first time you run the function in a given process, and (2) Numba uses fixed precision integers which you are overflowing given the input of `100`. Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to get at?

Comment: 1. First for value 10 I got 144 ( 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144 ) . 2. The jit is slower with print and not without this print function. 3. The jit and the function result is not the same - overflowed as you say.I need a good solution.

Comment: Most of comments show me a way of how is working . Anyway not a solution to improve the code with numba. I will get this answer like solve !

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the slowdown is the compilation time. The first time an un-signatured numba-jitted function is called it will inspect the types and compile the function for these arguments. Subsequent runs will be faster because it's already compiled:

```
for _ in range(5):
    start = timer()
    fibonacci_jit(100)
    print(timer() - start)

0.18958417814776496      # first run - includes compilation
6.1441049545862825e-06
3.3513299761978033e-06
3.3513299761978033e-06
3.3513299761978033e-06
```

However, because numba uses C types your integers are subject to overflow. You can easily inspect the types:

```
fibonacci_jit.inspect_types()

fibonacci (int64,)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# File: <ipython-input-19-a73271f1a552>
# --- LINE 3 --- 
# label 0
#   del $const0.1
#   del $0.4
#   del $0.2
#   del $0.3

def fibonacci(n):

    # --- LINE 4 --- 
    #   n = arg(0, name=n)  :: int64
    #   $const0.1 = const(tuple, (1, 1))  :: (int64 x 2)
    #   $0.4 = exhaust_iter(value=$const0.1, count=2)  :: (int64 x 2)
    #   $0.2 = static_getitem(value=$0.4, index=0, index_var=None)  :: int64
    #   $0.3 = static_getitem(value=$0.4, index=1, index_var=None)  :: int64
    #   a = $0.2  :: int64
    #   b = $0.3  :: int64
    #   jump 8
    # label 8

    a, b = 1, 1

    # --- LINE 5 --- 
    #   jump 10
    # label 10
    #   $10.1 = global(range: <class 'range'>)  :: Function(<class 'range'>)
    #   $10.3 = call $10.1(n, func=$10.1, args=[Var(n, <ipython-input-19-a73271f1a552> (4))], kws=(), vararg=None)  :: (int64,) -> range_state_int64
    #   del n
    #   del $10.1
    #   $10.4 = getiter(value=$10.3)  :: range_iter_int64
    #   del $10.3
    #   $phi18.1 = $10.4  :: range_iter_int64
    #   del $10.4
    #   jump 18
    # label 18
    #   $18.2 = iternext(value=$phi18.1)  :: pair<int64, bool>
    #   $18.3 = pair_first(value=$18.2)  :: int64
    #   $18.4 = pair_second(value=$18.2)  :: bool
    #   del $18.2
    #   $phi20.1 = $18.3  :: int64
    #   $phi38.1 = $18.3  :: int64
    #   del $phi38.1
    #   del $18.3
    #   $phi38.2 = $phi18.1  :: range_iter_int64
    #   del $phi38.2
    #   branch $18.4, 20, 38
    # label 20
    #   del $18.4
    #   i = $phi20.1  :: int64
    #   del i
    #   del $phi20.1
    #   del $20.4
    #   del $a20.5

    for i in range(n):

        # --- LINE 6 --- 
        #   $20.4 = a + b  :: int64
        #   $a20.5 = a  :: int64
        #   a = $20.4  :: int64
        #   b = $a20.5  :: int64
        #   jump 18
        # label 38
        #   del b
        #   del $phi20.1
        #   del $phi18.1
        #   del $18.4
        #   jump 40
        # label 40
        #   del a

        a, b = a+b, a

    # --- LINE 7 --- 
    #   $40.2 = cast(value=a)  :: int64
    #   return $40.2

    return a


================================================================================
```

At least on my computer it uses `int64` so the maximum possible value is `9223372036854775807`. You can't get around that with numba. If you need arbitrary precision integers you have to stick to Python.

Comment: I need a good solution: 1. try with print in and out time loop , 2.also for value 10 I got 144 ( 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144 ) 3. The jit and the function result is not the same - overflowed but I need something to work.

Comment: Cool. Then just don't use numba here and stick with Python integers.